# how to share specific folder to specific computer without password in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-sharing, shared-folders

So I have this problem. I want to share a folder to specific computer without password. I do not want to share it to everyone. The scenario is that there is a one computer, and wants to share the specific folder to specific computer without password. Password protected sharing is turned off.

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can create a user on your computer and share the folder to that user. On the other computer, when you access the share, it will still popup a username/password dialog though, so technically that is a share protected by a password.

But if you fill in the username/password, then check "remember credentials", it will not ask it again.

If you match the username and password to the one used on the other computer, it will not even ask, until they change their password.

Comment: i don't want to do that because they are so many computers to change and they share files to "everyone" so no password is needed. But there are some files that i don't want them to see, only specific computers.

Comment: Yes, so you create an additional user on your pc, share the folder specifically to that user, and no one else can access it. They'll get a login prompt if they attempt it. You can also append the share with a $ and it becomes a hidden share. You then actually have to know the share name to access it. If you use everyone, no password is needed, but if the share leaks out, anyone can access it. And it can be scanned for by people that know what they're doing.

Comment: *So many computers to change*...are these machines part of a domain? That would significantly expand your available options.